# How to generate nodejs express application with reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using `reactjs` in my application as front end technology. I need to use `nodejs` as server side programming.

I setup the `reactjs` application, it has generated project structure and package.json then I installed the `express`, npm itself has added it into package.json

I created a `server` directory inside my application for server side code. Here is my directory and package.json

```
{
  "name": "rock-paper-scissors-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Project Structure:

[image]

So far everything is good. Now I want to generate `node-js` express application https://github.com/expressjs/express which should not override my existing like `package.json`

> $ express ??

Can anyone help what is the method of it ? or Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install express inside server directory. Go inside server directory by `cd server` and type `express myapp`. This will generate a complete separate express app using different `package.json` file.

**note**: Expressjs generator must be installed before `express myapp` command. You can install expressjs generator by `npm install -g express-generator`

Since this is not a good idea for going full-stack in react. You can consider a couple of starter kits for this task.

1. [mern.io](http://mern.io)
   This stands for: mongo, express, react and nodejs. This comes with pre-configured React Router, Redux and Server side rendering.
2. [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit)

> React Starter Kit — isomorphic web app boilerplate (Node.js, Express, GraphQL, React.js, Babel, PostCSS, Webpack, Browsersync)